# Debugging RMI application with Ecllipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I have an RMI application that have multiple Peers. I wish to make use of Eclipse IDE to debug it (setting breakpoint etc.). How to running multiple Peers at the same time while be able to setting breakpoint? Thanks.

Currently I am using windows 7 command line, open multiple command line windows, and test multiple Peers a the same time. (of course we need to start rmiregistry using the command line windows before testing)

I am open to other IDE that can better debug these types of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should start your applications with option:
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y

thus the applications can stop to wait for the connection and then you can use IDE to do remote debug.

Comment: Thanks, I have two questions: 1. Do you mean set them in Eclipse for the command line "
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y"; 2. For other connections, I need to start them in command line or IDE?

Comment: NO, start your application in command, it will wait for connection on port 8787 which controlled by suspend=y. so after you connect to the port from eclipse(start remote debug) the application can continue run which give u time to set breakpoint before the code is executed.